# Can I draw and animate vectors in iOS without resorting to bitmap images?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can I do this?

My question arises from the need of a button that I'm animating when a user touches it.

This animation has been made with a set of 30 png images (half a second of animation @ 60FPS). This totals 60 images for regular and retina screens. It works quite well this way, but I'm not happy about it.

My goals are:

1 - Drastically reduce the size of my app (e.g my background is a 400KB png file, but with quartz I can do it with a dozen lines of code).

2 - Do with it with a perfect, smooth animation, as light on the CPU/GPU as I can.

So, is there anyway I can do this?

I have the images in pure vector, and I can draw them with Quartz. But not animate it without having to redraw everything for every frame. (Well, the animation is a "2 way street", it's the coming back that would be problematic to redraw)

Are there any APIs/Frameworks that would help me do this? How would I go about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [CAShapeLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html). It's `path` property is animatable. For an animation to look good it's important that the from & to shape in the animation have the same amount of points. So depending on your shapes this might or might not work.